# How do i see the progess of mysql dump?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, percona

I use the following command to restore mysql dump.

```
mysql --defaults-file=/apps/mysql/instance/db01/my.cnf-UTIL < abc.sql
```

How will I be able to see the progress of the restore?

Answer (score 2):

I do it like this:

```
pv -pert abc.sql | mysql --defaults-file=/apps/mysql/instance/db01/my.cnf-UTIL
```

[pv](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pv) is the Linux tool to "monitor the progress of data through a pipe."

The output with the `-pert` options looks like this:

```
0:00:29 [1.98MiB/s] [===>                                     ] 10% ETA 0:03:54
```

As the `pv` command reads through the file and passes it to `mysql`, the progress bar advances, the time updates, and so on. It's really handy.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-v` option to produce verbose output. It will show each query as it's being executed.

```
mysql -v --defaults-file=/apps/mysql/instance/db01/my.cnf-UTIL < abc.sql
```

You can also use `-vv` or `-vvv` to add increasing amounts of detail in the output, such as the number of rows affected and the amount of time taken by the query.